# How to get Windows 7 to open directories with single click and files with double click?

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtualbox, mouse, touchpad

I've got a Windows 7 VM (VirtualBox) running on my Macbook, and I'm slowly working my way towards a configuration that gives as consistent behavior as possible between OS X and Windows.

In OS X Finder **in Column mode**, folders are opened with a single click, but file open requires a double click (which to my mind makes sense now that I've been using my Macbook a while).  But in Windows 7, I appear to only be able to chose from either "Single click to open an item" or "Double click to open an item", with "items" being both files *and* directories.

Is there a way to get consistent behavior in both OS's?  I'd prefer it if I could make Win7 open directories on single click but files on double click; but if there was a way to get OS X Finder in Column Mode to open folders *and* files only on double click, I'd take that too...

Comment: I'll check when I get home today, but I'm decently sure that my MacBook Pro opens folders only with a doubleclick.

Comment: I just realized I wasn't clear -- I'm using Finder in Column Mode, and by "Opens" I mean opens in the next column to the right

Comment: Ah, now your question makes a bit more sense :) You might want to edit your question to include that clarification for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for consistent behavior on both OSes, I would switch finder to the same details-style view that windows explorer uses. This will provide similar layouts and click/selection properties across both operating systems.

Comment: Only icon view is similar. List view/details view is vastly superior (except for column options) than that of Windows Explorer.

Comment: Perhaps, but I would think the general interaction (# of clicks) and visual layout are somewhat similar. I personally still hate the fact that I can't get folders to sort to the top on my Mac, though.